# Example of an $F: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow [0,1]$ that is not a 2D distribution function?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

I would like to find an example of $F: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow [0,1]$, which is NOT a two-dimensional cdf, such that

i) $F$ is right-continuous i.e. $lim_{(x',y')\downarrow(x,y)} F(x',y') = F(x,y)$

ii) $lim_{(x\rightarrow\infty,y\rightarrow\infty)}F(x,y)=1$ , $lim_{(x\downarrow-\infty)}F(x,y)=0$ $\forall x$, $lim_{(y\downarrow-\infty)}F(x,y)=0$ $\forall y$.

iii) $x\leq x',$ $y\leq y'$ implies $F(x,y)\leq F(x',y')$.

What kind of function can be presented as an example?

$+$ Is there any difference between the condition iii) and the monotonicity definition of a joint distribution function I missed? Related to this point, which factor can define a function as NOT a cdf? For any example given, what will be the important parts I need to prove?

Comment: Try $$F(x,y)=\mathbf 1_{x+y\geqslant1}$$ then $\tfrac13+\frac23\geqslant1$ hence $$F(\tfrac13,\tfrac23)=F(\tfrac23,\tfrac13)=1$$ hence if $F=F_{X,Y}$, then $P(A)=P(B)=1$ with $$A=[X\leqslant\tfrac13,Y\leqslant\tfrac23]\qquad B=[X\leqslant\tfrac23,Y\leqslant\tfrac13]$$ but $$P(A\cap B)=P(X\leqslant\tfrac13,Y\leqslant\tfrac13)=F(\tfrac13,\tfrac13)=0$$ although $P(A)=P(B)=1$ implies $P(A\cap B)=1$.

Comment: @Did I am sorry for the late reply, and sincerely appreciate your advice. I felt very helpful dealing with probability measure thanks to you.