# Example of a function $F:\mathbb R^2 \to [0,1]$ that is not a two-dimensional distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm trying to find an example of a $F:\mathbb R^2 \to [0,1]$ such that:

1. $F$ is right-continuous i.e. $\lim_{(x',y')\downarrow(x,y)} F(x',y') = F(x,y)$
2. $\lim_{(x\rightarrow\infty,y\rightarrow\infty)}F(x,y)=1$ , $\lim_{(x\downarrow-\infty)}F(x,y)=0$ $\forall x$, $\lim_{(y\downarrow-\infty)}F(x,y)=0$ $\forall y$
3. $F$ is non-decreasing in $x$ and $y$

but $F$ isn't a 2-dimensional distribution function. I noticed a duplicate [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1953253/example-of-an-f-mathbbr2-rightarrow-0-1-that-is-not-a-2d-distribution), but do not really understand the example in there, so I'm trying to come up with a different example.

Any help or advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example in the earlier post is very simple, so I will try to explain why that example works. Let $F(x,y)=1$ if $x+y \geq 1$ and $0$ otherwise. If this is a distribution function then there would be random variables $X,Y$ such that $F(x,y)=P\{X\leq x, Y \leq Y\}$. Consider $P\{0<X\leq 1, 0<Y \leq 1\}$. We can write this as $P\{X\leq 1, 0<Y \leq 1\} -P\{X\leq 0, 0<Y \leq 1\}$. Repeating this for the second variable we can write it as $P\{X\leq 1, Y \leq 1\}-P\{X\leq 0, Y \leq 1\}-P\{X\leq 1, Y \leq 0\}+P\{X\leq 0, Y \leq 0\}$. And this becomes $F(1,1)-F(0,1)-F(1,0)+F(0,0)$. For our function this is $1-1-1+0=-1$. Thus we got an event with negative probability which is impossible. Hence $F$ is not a distribution function. You can verify that it has properties 1) 2) and 3).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When you're trying to come up with examples like this, or just in general, what's the strategy/intuition to get you started? What thought process runs through to arrive at such an example?